# Change background-image with jQuery - doesn´t work

Tags: jquery

```
$('#areaView').css('background-image', 'url(/areaNr1.jpg)');
```

I don´t know what to say, I have no idea why this code doesn´t work. The old background-image disappears, but the new one never appears.

I have checked and areaNr1.jpg exists in the same folder as the code. Allthough the function isn´t in the same folder as #areaView, but that should not matter, right?

Any ideas why this doesn´t work?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have an image at `{your domain}/areaNr1.jpg`?

Comment: The code I provided is in mydomain.com/jQuery/myfile.js and the image also is in that folder.

Comment: Then here is your issue: Your script is pointing to mydomain.com/areaNr1.jpg when (as I understood) your file is mydomain.com/jQuery/areaNr1.jpg

Comment: can you give us the proper directory structure? Where is the js file located? Where is the jpg file located? and where is the html file(that includes this script)
 located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The code I provided is in mydomain.com/jQuery/myfile.js and the image also is in that folder.

Then you mustn't prefix the URL with a `/` - that makes it point to the web root.

Use just `areaNr1.jpg` - note hoever that the URL will be relative to the HTML file, not the JS file in this case so you may need to change the path further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the argument to url():

```
$('#areaView').css('background-image', 'url("/areaNr1.jpg")');
```

Comment: Nope, quotes are optional if the URL doesn't contain a space

Answer (score 0):

Since the image is at `mydomain.com/jQuery/areaNr1.jpg`, you need to include the folder, too. If it was CSS, you could make it relative to CSS's folder, but not with JS.

```
$('#areaView').css('background-image', 'url("jQuery/areaNr1.jpg")');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the html file that is running the jQuery is in the same folder as your image try:

```
$('#areaView').css("background", "url('areaNr1.jpg')");
```

If the image is in a folder it would be

```
$('#areaView').css("background", "url('folder/areaNr1.jpg')");
```

or if its in the directory above

```
$('#areaView').css("background", "url('../areaNr1.jpg')");
```

If the image is in /JQuery where is the html file?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#areaView').css('background-image', 'url(/jQuery/areaNr1.jpg)');
```

this might solve the problem